# Drawing a compound image from smaller images

Tags: android, canvas, drawing

I want to draw an image on canvas constituted from smaller images, and make the new compound image scroll-able both horizontally and vertically as well as enable zoom-in, zoom-out and pan functionality. Any suggestions as to which View (container) I should use?